# Using SWT's ImageData, how to tell if a png, gif, bmp files have transparency?

Tags: java, image, swt, transparency, alpha

As the title says.

I try to determine if a given image file has transparency (non-opaque) or not.

Is this the correct way:

```
public static boolean hasAlpha(ImageData imageData) {
    if (imageData.alpha != -1 || imageData.transparentPixel != -1)
        return true;
    if (imageData.alphaData == null && imageData.maskData == null)
        return false;
    if (imageData.alphaData != null)
        for (int i = 0; i < imageData.alphaData.length; ++i) {
            byte alpha = imageData.alphaData[i];
            if (alpha !=0xFF)
                return true;
        }
    if (imageData.maskData != null)
        for (int i = 0; i < imageData.maskData.length; ++i)
            if (imageData.maskData[i] != 0xFF)
                return true;
    return false;
}
```

?

Is there a better way than to go over the entire alpha channel (using the loop I made) ? Maybe a way without even decoding the entire image file into decoded large bitmap?

Comment: You might also need to look at the transparency mask data in `maskData`.

Comment: @greg-449 How is it even used? Anyway, if it's not null, does it mean it has alpha? I think it's only an additional metadata of the image, to show a tiny version of it, no? So I think it's not needed to be checked.

Comment: No, it appears to be a bit mask with a single bit per pixel in the main image, where a 1 bit means alpha is 255 and zero alpha 0. Generally used by calling ImageData.getTransparencyMask

Comment: @greg-449 Are you sure? according to this: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fgraphics%2FImageData.html , it says it's of an icon: "An icon-specific field containing the data from the icon mask." . Also, if it's of the main image, what's "alphaData" for? It seems to be the exact meaning of alpha pixels, each alpha for one pixel...

Comment: @greg-449 Maybe "icon" is for a specific file format? But then why do it this way? To save bits? Each bit there is of a single pixel : opaque/transparent?

Comment: So, suppose "imageData.maskData" is not null, does 0 for a cell in the array mean there is not transparency in 8 pixels there ? I've updated the code in the question. Does it seem correct now?

Comment: I think something is wrong in the docs about "alphaData" : it says the value is supposed to be from 0 to 255, while 255 is fully opaque, yet what I see is that there is also a value of -1 .

Comment: The Java `byte` type is actually a signed value from -128 to 127. You get 255 using `byte & 0xFF`.

Comment: @greg-449 hmmm... forgot about this. The docs should be updated I think, no? I do remember that it was annoying to handle bytes on java though :)

Comment: But the other stuff I wrote is ok?

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems.

`ImageData.alpha` could be set to 255 which means fully opaque, only 0-254 transparent.

`ImageData.alphaData` for each byte only a value of 255 is fully opaque.

`ImageData.maskData` all bits of each byte have to be 1 for the mask to be opaque.

You might also want to think what 'transparent' means. An alpha value of 254 means the image is only very slightly transparent and a value of 0 means the image is not visible at all.

Comment: by "transparent" i mean it's not 100% opaque, just like glass that's transparent even if it gets a bit dirty, as you can see through it . Can you please show the correct code? I've modified the code, as I think I wrote it in the opposite logic. Is it now ok?

Comment: Say, if I add a check that imageData.type==SWT.IMAGE_JPEG , this can also determine if the image doesn't have transparency (because jpg doesn't support it), but for some reason, I get -1 for the type. How could it be?